# Windows 7 will boot with some users not others

Tags: windows, crash

I am using windows 7 and for my administrator user i am able to log in but before my system even loads up completely I receive a blue screen and a crash this, i use this account primarily when it is working.  Upon logging into another user account which i have barely used I have no problems other than some redirection when clicking google links what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Corrupted user registry hive.

You could probably get it working again using system restore, otherwise just start over with a new user account.